# glColor3f not working on gluSphere

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glu

I am currently rendering a solar system of planets in my 3d space but every single planet is black even when light hits the sphere. The spheres are rendered last in my render function. Had the colors working when the spheres were being rendered on their own but now i've added my sky box and other quads all the spheres refuse to be colored.

```
    #include "Scene.h"

float rotation;
float rotation2;
int direction;
int speed;




Scene::Scene(Input *in)
{
    // Initialise variables
    rotation = 20;
    rotation2 = 0;
    direction = 1;
    speed = 5;
    myTexture = 0;
    skyBox = 0;

    // Store pointer for input class
    input = in;

    // OpenGL settings
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enable Smooth Shading
    glClearColor(0.39f, 0.58f, 93.0f, 1.0f);            // Cornflour Blue Background
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                                 // Depth Buffer Setup
    glClearStencil(0);                                  // Clear stencil buffer
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Enables Depth Testing
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);                              // Enables Lighting
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Really Nice Perspective Calculations

    // Other OpenGL / render setting should be applied here.
    myTexture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
        (
            "gfx/neongrid.png",
            SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
            SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
            SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
            );
    skyBox = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
        (
            "gfx/starField.png",
            SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
            SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
            SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
            );
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GL_NEAREST);

    camera = new Camera();
}

void Scene::update(float dt)
{
    // Update camera position
    camera->update(input, dt);

    // Handle user input
        if (input->isKeyDown(43))
        {
            direction = 1;
            input->SetKeyUp(43);
        }
        else if (input->isKeyDown(45))
        {
            direction = -1;
            input->SetKeyUp(45);
        }

    // Update scene related variables
        rotation += speed * dt;
        rotation2 += (speed *2) * dt;

        if (input->isKeyDown('p') && WF == false)
        {
            WF = true;
            input->SetKeyUp('p');
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
        }
        if (input->isKeyDown('p') && WF == true)
        {
            WF = false;
            input->SetKeyUp('p');
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
        }

    // Calculate FPS for output
    calculateFPS();
}

void Scene::render() {


    // Clear Color and Depth Buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Reset transformations
    glLoadIdentity();
    // Set the camera
    gluLookAt(camera->getPosition().x, camera->getPosition().y, camera->getPosition().z,
        camera->getLookAt().x, camera->getLookAt().y, camera->getLookAt().z,
        camera->getUp().x, camera->getUp().y, camera->getUp().z);

    glutWarpPointer(400, 300);
    glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_FULL_CROSSHAIR);

    // Lighting
    GLfloat Light_Ambient[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat Light_Diffuse[] = { 9.0f, 9.0f, 9.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat Light_Position[] = { 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f };


    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, Light_Ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, Light_Diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, Light_Position);


    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

#pragma region skybox 
    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(camera->getPosition().x, camera->getPosition().y, camera->getPosition().z);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyBox);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //Back
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    //Right 
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    //front
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    //left
    glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    //top
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    //bottom
    glNormal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glNormal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glEnd();
#pragma endregion

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
#pragma region wall
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexture);
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // first face
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // second face
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // third face
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // fourth face
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTexture);
    glScalef(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // first face
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // second face
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // third face
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    // fourth face
    glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    glEnd();
#pragma endregion
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();

    // Render sun
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL);
    glTranslatef(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), 0.20, 20, 20);
    glPushMatrix(); // Push for default matrix

                    // Render Planet 1
    glRotatef(rotation, 0.5, 0.5, 0);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 1);
    glScalef(1, 1, 1);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
    gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), 0.20, 10, 10);
    glPopMatrix(); // Pop off stack back to sun matrix
    glPushMatrix(); // Push for default matrix

                    // Render Planet 2
    glRotatef(rotation2, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
    glScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), 0.20, 5, 5);
    glPushMatrix(); // Pop back to sun

                    // Render a moon around Planet 2
    glRotatef((rotation*2.0), 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(1.5, 0, 0);
    glScalef(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), 0.20, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix(); // Pop to planet 2
    glPushMatrix(); // Push for default matrix

                    // Render a SECOND moon around Planet 2
    glRotatef((rotation * 2), 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(1.5, 0, 0);
    glScalef(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), 0.20, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix();
    //glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix(); // Go back to sun!
    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(2, 2, 2);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), 0.5, 20, 20);

    glPopMatrix();

    // End render geometry --------------------------------------

    // Render text, should be last object rendered.
    renderTextOutput();

    // Swap buffers, after all objects are rendered.
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

// Handles the resize of the window. If the window changes size the perspective matrix requires re-calculation to match new window size.
void Scene::resize(int w, int h) 
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
    // Prevent a divide by zero, when window is too short
    // (you cant make a window of zero width).
    if (h == 0)
        h = 1;

    float ratio = (float)w / (float)h;
    fov = 45.0f;
    nearPlane = 0.1f;
    farPlane = 100.0f;

    // Use the Projection Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    // Reset Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Set the viewport to be the entire window
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Set the correct perspective.
    gluPerspective(fov, ratio, nearPlane, farPlane);

    // Get Back to the Modelview
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);


}

// Calculates FPS
void Scene::calculateFPS()
{

    frame++;
    time = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

    if (time - timebase > 1000) {
        sprintf_s(fps, "FPS: %4.2f", frame*1000.0 / (time - timebase));
        timebase = time;
        frame = 0;
    }
}

// Compiles standard output text including FPS and current mouse position.
void Scene::renderTextOutput()
{
    // Render current mouse position and frames per second.
    sprintf_s(mouseText, "Mouse: %i, %i", input->getMouseX(), input->getMouseY());
    displayText(-1.f, 0.96f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f, mouseText);
    displayText(-1.f, 0.90f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f, fps);
}

// Renders text to screen. Must be called last in render function (before swap buffers)
void Scene::displayText(float x, float y, float r, float g, float b, char* string) {
    // Get Lenth of string
    int j = strlen(string);

    // Swap to 2D rendering
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 5, 100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    // Orthographic lookAt (along the z-axis).
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Set text colour and position.
    glColor3f(r, g, b);
    glRasterPos2f(x, y);
    // Render text.
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12, string[i]);
    }
    // Reset colour to white.
    glColor3f(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);

    // Swap back to 3D rendering.
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(fov, ((float)width/(float)height), nearPlane, farPlane);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Updated sun code :

```
// Render sun
glTranslatef(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), 0.20, 20, 20);
glPushMatrix(); // Push for default matrix
                // Render Planet 1
glRotatef(rotation, 0.5, 0.5, 0);
glTranslatef(0, 0, 1);
glScalef(1, 1, 1);
glColor3f(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), 0.20, 10, 10);
glPopMatrix(); // Pop off stack back to sun matrix
glPushMatrix(); // Push for default matrix
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out i was missing a OpenGL setting

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

Inserted at the start of Scene

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to end glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); with glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); after you render sun.
2. If problem appeared after you added skybox. Check if vertices are in right order.

Comment: I decided to remove gl_texture_2d as it didnt actually make a difference to the spheres they just become slightly lighter, my sky box vertices are all mapped out on paper so should be fine. Been stuck here for a few hours now OpenGL is bothersome.

Comment: so can you post new code ? And a ss from what you see might be helpfull

Comment: Yep that was mateiral colors... Sory for not answearing i was in no internet zone for almost a week